# How to make CDT/Eclipse work with C++11 threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, eclipse-cdt

I tried to test an example of C++11 threads in Eclipse. But I got this message when running the program:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>   what():  Operation not permitted'

My system: ubuntu + gcc 4.7

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void worker()
{
    std::cout << "hello from worker" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::thread t(worker);
    t.join();
}
```

...and yes, I put `-std=c++11` and `-pthread` inside `C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> Cross G++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous -> Other Flags`.

Any comments?

Comment: Looks strange to put those settings in a "cross compiler" section (but I don't know Eclipse). The crash is repeatable if the `-pthread` flag is not present on the command line and you have other versions of libstdc++ installed. So make sure that flag is really being passed to your compiler

Comment: This is a runtime exception, so the code compiles correctly. Still I dont understand in which cases this exception message should occur...

Comment: @Klaim: that error comes up if you link against the wrong libstdc++, which can happen if you have multiple versions of it installed and you don't pass `-pthread` (or your GCC install is borked)

Comment: I think `-pthread` is passed to compiler, because I put it in the same place that I put `-std=c++11`, and the code won't be compiled when I did not put `-std=c++11`. A more strange thing is that the code works correctly when I compile it from command line manually.

Comment: That error definitely happens when `-pthread` isn't used (even if you only have one libstdc++ installed).  Make sure `-pthread` is used for the compiler command **and** the linker command.  Otherwise libpthread.so won't be linked to and threads cannot be launched at runtime.

Comment: Shouldn't it be -lpthread? And since it is a linker command it needs to be in a different place than -std=c++11....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was solved by the comment of Jonathan Wakely.

I added `-pthread` to `C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> Cross G++ **Linker** -> Miscellaneous -> Other Flags` and the program worked correctly.

Thank you Jonathan.

Comment: For me it was `... -> CCC C++ Linker -> Miscellaneous -> Linker flags`

Comment: hmm, that makes my program run & debug okey in eclipse, but the syntax checker still gives me errors when I use std::thread or thread.join. Anybody know how to solve that too?

Answer (score 1):

To work C++11 `std::thread` in Eclipse, one needs to give `-pthread` option while compiling. However **that's not enough**. In my Ubuntu 14.04, with Eclipse Kepler and g++4.9 below makes it work:

1. Right click on Project and select 'Properties'
2. Go to 'C/C++ Build' > 'Settings' > (tab) 'Tool Settings'
3. First select 'Cross G++ Compiler' > 'Miscellaneous' > 'Other flags';
   and add
   `-pthread` after `-std=c++11`
4. Second select 'Cross G++ Linker' > 'Libraries';
   and add `pthread` (which is equivalent
   to command line `-lpthread`)

Finally re-compile the project; the error should go.

Also remember that if you use, `std::thread` then its object must be `join()` somewhere. Else you may get below runtime error:

> terminate called without an active exception

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Preprocessor include paths, etc > Providers > CDT GCC Builtin Compiler Settings** and append `-std=c++11` to the compiler specs.

   You can also do this for all projects going to **Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Settings > Discovery** and append `-std=c++11` to the **CDT GCC Builtin Compiler Settings** specs.

   ```
    ${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD -std=c++11 "${INPUTS}"
   ```
2. **Project Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Miscellaneous > Other flags**, add `-pthread -std=c++11 -Wl,--no-as-needed`:

   ```
    -c -fmessage-length=0 -pthread -std=c++11 -Wl,--no-as-needed
   ```
3. **Project Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > GCC C++ Linker > Miscellaneous > Linker flags**, add `-pthread -std=c++11 -Wl,--no-as-needed`

   ```
    -pthread -std=c++11 -Wl,--no-as-needed
   ```