# Eclipse Neon 3 - C++ 11 Threads

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading

I have a problem with using Threads in C++. I read this topic:
[How to make CDT/Eclipse work with C++11 threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395936/how-to-make-cdt-eclipse-work-with-c11-threads)
But it didn't help at all :(
So, from the beginning. I'm trying to 'convert' big project from Visual Studio into Eclipse and I'm forcing with a problem with threads. So I created another Eclipse project in order to test that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void worker()
{
    std::cout << "hello from worker" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::thread t(worker);
    t.join();
}
```

But, I get:

> error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'

In GCC C++ Compiler->Miscellaneous I have

```
-c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -pthread
```

In MinGW C++ Linker->Libraries I have

```
pthread
```

Even in MinGW C++ Linker->Miscellaneous I have

```
-std=c++11
```

I'm a fresh user of Eclipse and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
I would be very grateful for any tips :)

Comment: This is from a few (quite a few) years back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519607/stdthread-error-thread-not-member-of-std might help you

Comment: Why dont you just use visual c++ compiler. Honestly visual cpp has alot of non standard cpp its easier to either start from scratch or stick with it. [using visual c++ compiler in eclipse](http://codewriterstips.blogspot.ug/2012/05/using-microsoft-c-compiler-with-eclipse.html)

Comment: which compiler version are you using?

Comment: I'm using GCC(MinGW-W64) 7.1.0